# How to use Map[List[String], String]?

Tags: scala

I have a map:

```
val m: Map[List[String], String] = Map (
    List("banana", "melon", "apple") -> "fruit",
    List("chair", "table", "wardrobe") -> "furniture")
```

How to check, what is e.g. `banana`? This ofc doesn't work:

```
scala> m("banana")
```

I could split the lists into single entries `String -> String`, but there are lots of them, so I prefer `List[String] -> String`.

Comment: Why is the key a list and not reversed? usually I use my maps with a key of single and list of values?

Comment: You can't, as simple as that. A **Map** work by retiring a value by its key, period. There is no magic for making it work for sub-parts of a key. You can of course filter the map and do some processing as most answers suggest, but then you lost the property of **O(1)** access, which then implies that it would just be better to have a list of tuples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I could split the lists into single entries `String -> String`, but there are lots of them, so I prefer `List[String] -> String`.

That doesn't sound like a very good reason to me. The whole point of using a map is easy and quick access to values. Using a list as the key type when you'll be looking up values by elements of that list just makes it hard to use the map, while giving almost no advantages.

I suggest you "flatten" your map, so one key maps to one value with possibly duplicate values:

```
val m: Map[List[String], String] = Map(
  List("banana", "melon", "apple") -> "fruit",
  List("chair", "table", "wardrobe") -> "furniture"
)

val flattenedMap = m.flatMap { case (keys, value) =>
  keys.map(_ -> value)
}

flattenedMap("banana")
```

If you're not yet comfortable with using `flatMap`, you can use a for-comprehension instead, which works very nicely on this example:

```
val m: Map[List[String], String] = Map(
  List("banana", "melon", "apple") -> "fruit",
  List("chair", "table", "wardrobe") -> "furniture"
)

val flattenedMap: Map[String, String] = for {
  (keys, value) <- m // for each list of keys and value in your map
  key <- keys        // and for each key from the list of keys
} yield (key, value) // create a pair of key and value
```

This yields the same result as the example with `flatMap` above.

Or you could just initialize your `Map` as a "flattened" map immediately:

```
val flattenedMap: Map[String, String] = Map(
  "banana" -> "fruit",
  "melon" -> "fruit",
  "apple" -> "fruit",
  "chair" -> "furniture",
  "table" -> "furniture",
  "wardrobe" -> "furniture"
)

flattenedMap("banana")
```

Comment: I like your example with `flatMap`! I still have problems with understanding this method...

Comment: @Rafaó I always find it useful to think about `flatMap` as if you applied `map` and then `flatten` - hence the name.

Comment: @Rafaó I added another example with a for-comprehension which may be easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it. I can use `foreach` to check every key:

```
m foreach (x => println(x._1.contains("banana")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this:

```
 map.keys.flatten.exists(s => s == "banana")
```

The `flatten` maps all lists of lists to a single list. `exists` checks if banana is in that list.

Comment: The original question is "what is banana", not "do we have a knowledge of what banana is" ;-)

Comment: I think what @bobah wanted to say is that your solution returns `true` or `false`, depending on whether `banana` appears in any of the keys lists, but it doesn't return the value (i.e. `fruit`).

Answer (score 0):

If it's a one-off lookup, then any lazy (the one that does not create unnecessary container copies) combo would do (I normalized them all to return `Option`):

```scala
m.withFilter(_._1.contains("banana")).map(_._2).headOption
// or
m.find(_._1.contains("banana")).map(_._2)
// or
(for ((k, v) <- m.toStream if k.contains("banana")) yield v).headOption
```

Otherwise, if this query needs to run often you might want to change this data structure for faster lookups with

```scala
val mm: immutable.Map[String, String] = m.flatMap{ case (k,v) => k.map(_ -> v)}
...
print(mm["banana"])
```